# How to install Wine 1.7.50 on mac

Tags: osx, wine

I want to install WineHQ 1.7.50 on macbook pro as it supports DirectX11. I tried installing it from source but I get random warnings but no errors were thrown.

> ./configure
>
> make depend
>
> make
>
> make install

I typed command `which wine` as it shows me path where wine got installed(I guess).

`/usr/local/bin/wine`

However, when I type `wine install.exe` command or any other `--version` wine is not found.